# gitlab api get issue including time_stats

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

when I pull issues with a private token I'm getting everything but the time_stats with the issues.

```
api/v4/issues
```

Do I need some special queries for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I had the same issue today (v9.5.6). Please update to the latest version (now on v10.0.2).